# oracle update con php

Tags: php

Buenas quiero hacer un update desde php a una base de datos oracle.Pero me da el siguente fallo

> conexion realizada Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid
>   character in C:\xampp\htdocs\Reto\activacion.php on line 20

```
<?php 
$codigo=$_POST["codigo"];




$conn = oci_connect('admin', '123', '192.168.0.28/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}else{
    echo"conexion realizada";
}



$query = "UPDATE usuarios SET activacion= 0 WHERE codigo = '$codigo';";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que quitar el punto y coma al final de la sentencia:

```
$query = "UPDATE usuarios SET activacion= 0 WHERE codigo = '$codigo'";
```

Por esto que dice el [Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.oci-parse.php):

> Las sentencias SQL **no deberían finalizar con un punto y coma
>   (";")**. Las sentencias PL/SQL sí deberían finalizar con un punto y
>   coma (";").

---

### Nota sobre la seguridad

Considera dar seguridad a tu código aplicando el criterio de consultas preparadas.

```
$query = "UPDATE usuarios SET activacion= 0 WHERE codigo = :codigo";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":codigo", $codigo);
oci_execute($stid);
```

De ese modo blindarás tu código contra ataques de **Inyección SQL**.